# Is it possible to compile recently changed files first?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

The following scenario happens a lot:

- I change a header which is included in a lot of places, e.g. to add a function declaration.
- I add a function definition to the corresponding source file, which has an error because I'm dumb.
- I compile, and wait a long time for a bunch of irrelevant stuff to be compiled before I see the error in the code I'm working on.

If cmake would prioritize compiling recently modified files first, it would reduce my test cycle time in these cases by several minutes.  Is this possible?

Comment: What about compiling the changed file(s) with a separate (sub-)project (e.g. a testsuite), before glueing it to the big whole wild? That's probably more a question how you lay out your architectures horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Not in standard make.  I doubt if it is possible in `cmake` either.  Run the build in the background before adding the function definition?

Comment: You can build a specific **.o** file with makefile or ninja generators. By doing that, you could specifically build the .o file for the source that you changed.

Comment: All those other files will have to be recompiled anyway, so you're not really wasting any time, overall, unless fixing the source file also involves making some change to the same header file.

Comment: Lazy bugger am I. I cut and paste the command line for just the one file I'm interested in.

Comment: Potential approach: Use a shell command (`$(shell …)` in make, `execute_process` in CMake? I do not use CMake.) to list files in reverse order of modification time. Substitute the source extension (.c etc.) with the object module extension (.o or .obj). Now you have a list of objects in the order you want them built. Make them the dependents of a target, say OrderedObjects. Make that target.

Comment: @user4581301 One could also step into the build folder, and say `make <intermediate-bin-folder>/theChangedFile.o` simply executing the generated makefile.

Comment: Visual Studio has a button to compile the current file. I use it all the time...

Comment: @luqui Your question is spot on when it comes to even bigger build systems too. Building the necessary, testing the necessary etc. I want a single bit changed in a file to ripple out and trigger only the necessary builds/tests/whatnot... Having worked with creating build systems for a long time I know there are problems but "recent" isn't always the optimal. `make` and `ClearCase` (yes, oldschool I know) doesn't see eye to eye for example. `make` uses `<` to decide if a file has changed, but a change in a  `ClearCase` view may show very old files - so `make` sees them as unchanged ...

Comment: If a CMake expert coud confirm or deny whether or not CMake really has such a configuration point to specify this, if it doesn't I think this question might warrant closing in favour of questions which are specific to actual buildsystems.

Comment: @starball or answering in the negative with some links...

Comment: An answer like that might be a good candidate for a community wiki, since I'll bet that the average CMake expert is not also an expert with _every_ popular buildsystem supported by CMake. It might take a lot of collaboration. I imagine that the buildsystem-specific parts will require experts for each buildsystem, and then there's the matter of finding out whether-possible/how to make CMake do those things. I highly doubt such collaboration will happen without prompt. I think the next question is how to reach out to those experts, and whether they'll think it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything general in CMake that allows you to specify build order, but you may be able to do this with specific build system generators that allow you to compile individual .o or .obj files. For example, using the Ninja generator:

```
add_executable(mytarget the-suspect-src.cpp)
```

The generated Ninja build system lets me build the corresponding .o file by specifying it explicitly:

```sh
ninja CMakeFiles/mytarget.dir/the-suspect-src.cpp.o
```

So you could achieve your desired behavior with:

```sh
ninja CMakeFiles/mytarget.dir/the-suspect-src.cpp.o && ninja
```

Note that I don't memorize these paths to the .o files, but instead tab-complete in the terminal.

---

I happen to know that the Makefile generators also have a similar ability to build individual .o files, but I'm not aware of any other generators which have this ability.

Answer (score 1):

CMake isn't a build system. It's a buildsystem generator. It generates buildysstem configurations for buildsystems like Make, Ninja, Visual Studio, etc. Off the top of my head, I don't think CMake provides such a configuration point. I think you might have to dig into the docs for whichever specific buildsystem(s) you're using/generating.